# Watch Folder in VB.net/WPF

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I'm having a problem trying to work out how to watch a folder for changes. This is how far I've got:

```
Class MainWindow

<PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim Path As String = "C:\Temp"

    ' Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()
    watcher.Path = Path
    ' Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
    ' the renaming of files or directories. 
    watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.LastAccess Or NotifyFilters.LastWrite Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.DirectoryName)
    ' Only watch text files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt"

    ' Add event handlers.
    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf OnChanged
    AddHandler watcher.Renamed, AddressOf OnRenamed

    ' Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True

End Sub

' Define the event handlers.
Private Shared Sub OnChanged(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    ' Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
    MsgBox("File: " & e.FullPath & " " & e.ChangeType)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnRenamed(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As RenamedEventArgs)
    ' Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    MsgBox("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath)
End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is when a change occurs in the folder the program exits with no error code. I've read a few related posts and I know it has something to do with thread safety. However I've no idea how to make this program "thread safe". Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: Crashes with what? Null reference?

Comment: No sorry it doesn't "crash" as such, the program just exits with no error message

Comment: To help catch this kind of error in future, set "Break when an exception is thrown" on "common language runtime exceptions" in the Exceptions... window under the debug menu in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not getting any thread safety issues here.
I think the problem is:

```
MsgBox("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath)
```

should be

```
MsgBox(String.Format("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath))
```

Comment: Clearly this can only affect Renames.  If this doesn't solve the problem, please indicate what action you are performing on the files in the temp directory, in case that has some impact on the problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for this change it now works without exiting on rename! I can't believe I overlooked this. Also I'd only been testing the rename function of the code I've checked and the other handlers are working.